# React Router URL

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

In route.jsx my path looks like:

```
<Route path='/my-work/:workName' component={WorkShow} />
```

My link looks like:

```
<Link to={`/my-work/${props.work.name}`}>
```

I want to display the name in the url, but pass the id into the params instead so that I can fetch this in my component and pass it into the api.

My api path takes in the ID as a parameter but I want to avoid displaying this in the URL.

How would I store this as a key value pair....

Here is my reducer.js:

```
import Constants from '../constants';

const initialState = {
  projects: [],
  project: [],
  fetching: true,
};

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Constants.PROJECTS_FETCHING:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { fetching: true });

    case Constants.PROJECTS_RECEIVED:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { projects: action.proj, fetching: false });                  

    case Constants.PROJECT_FETCHING:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { fetching: true });

    case Constants.PROJECT_RECEIVED:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { project: action.project, fetching: false });                

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

And here is my action.js:

```
import Request from 'superagent';    
import Constants from '../constants';

const Actions = {
  fetchProjects: () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: Constants.PROJECTS_FETCHING });

    Request.get('/api/v1/projects')
        .then((data) => {                                            
          dispatch({     
            type: Constants.PROJECTS_RECEIVED,
            proj: data.body,                              
          });
        });                          
  },                                                                              fetchProject: projectId => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: Constants.PROJECT_FETCHING }); 

    Request.get('/api/v1/projects/' + projectId)          
      .then((data) => {
        dispatch({                  
          type: Constants.PROJECT_RECEIVED,                                               project: data.body,
        });
      });   
  },               
};  

export default Actions;
```

Comment: it's not possible, since when the user refreshes the page, all the data you have is in the url, so you need to use the name to fetch the data, or add the id in the url. of course, as a solution, you can save the id/name pairing in `localStorage` or something, but it's up to you how you want to handle it

Comment: you cannot do this directly, you can store the `id-name` mapping in your redux store and use it when you require to call the api

Comment: How would you store this in a redux store?